Tomcat fails to start due to error in tomcat-users.xml configuration
yesterday tomcat was working properly in my machine on eclipse , today tomcat failed to start even tho i didn't change anything
i was trying to run my JEE project on the tomcat server but it failed to run and then i tried to run the tomcat server alone after that i closed the project and it still doesn't run , and when i wanted to check for probelms there were an error in the settings file tomcat-users.xml
the error is cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'tomcat-users'.
the general configuration 
what's in the settings file 

What errors were shown in the Console output?

Have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSbmB7ZJ5zw
Basically, I had to change the URIs from http to https.
Instead of:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users version="1.0" 
  xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org tomcat-users.xsd">

  <!-- contents -->
</tomcat-users>

This one worked:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users version="1.0" 
  xmlns="https://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
  xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="https://tomcat.apache.org tomcat-users.xsd">

  <!-- contents -->
</tomcat-users>

